# Creating a Telegram Bot in Python for Automated Calls Based on Weather Conditions

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm working on a project where I plan to set up a Python server to function as either a Telegram bot or client. The goal is to have this bot/client make a call to me via Telegram under specific conditions. For instance, I have an external API that monitors the weather. If the temperature drops below 24 degrees, I want the system to call me on Telegram and play a pre-recorded message, like "Please wear a coat."

However, before diving into the complexities of weather-based triggers, I aim to start with something simpler. My initial target is to establish a basic chat functionality on Telegram. I want to be able to send a command (e.g., "!call") in the chat, which should prompt the system to initiate a Telegram voice call to me. It's crucial that these calls are made through Telegram, as I prefer not to use traditional phone calls.

In my attempts to implement this, I came across the 'pytgcalls' library. However, I'm struggling with its setup, particularly in understanding which credentials are required and how to effectively use the library. The documentation seems a bit unclear to me.

Can anyone provide guidance or examples on how to use 'pytgcalls' for this purpose? Any help in setting up this Telegram calling functionality would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: You will need to create a Telegram API key for programmatic access to your Telegram account. See https://core.telegram.org/api/obtaining_api_id#:~:text=Obtaining%20api_id&text=Log%20in%20to%20your%20Telegram,one%20api_id%20connected%20to%20it. on how to get one.

Comment: @FreekWiekmeijer Alright, I'll proceed with this approach, assuming I successfully obtain the key. Do you have any additional advice or tips?

Comment: Yes: go gradual. First thing to craete is a simple command line script in python with a `if __name__ == "__main__"` construct. In that script, try to connect to Telegram, then when it succeeds add a line to make a Telegram call. When you have that running, move the Telegram stuff behind a wrapper facade and preceed with the weather API integration.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @FreekWiekmeijer . I'm familiar with running Python scripts, so I'm primarily looking for specific guidance on 'pytgcalls'. Could you provide more details or examples for the code required to initiate a Telegram call? Additionally, any tips on handling authentication and managing call connections using this library would be incredibly helpful.

Comment: The PyPI page for the project (https://pypi.org/project/pytgcalls/) shows a code example using group calls. Gettting that to work (with a group of only you) may be the first step.